# Own lru_cache decorator in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, caching, decorator

I can't understand, why my own decorator "lru cache" doens't work.

```
def cache(max_size: int):
  
    dictionary = OrderedDict()

    def trace(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            cache_key = args + tuple(kwargs.items())
            if (cache_key not in dictionary) and (len(dictionary) < max_size):
                dictionary[cache_key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
            elif (cache_key not in dictionary) and (len(dictionary) == max_size):
                dictionary.popitem(last=False)
                dictionary[cache_key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                old_cache = dictionary[cache_key]
                del dictionary[cache_key]
                dictionary[cache_key] = old_cache

            return dictionary[cache_key]

        return wrapper

    return trace

@cache(20)
def binomial(n: int, k: int):
    if k > n:
        return 0
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    return binomial(n - 1, k) + binomial(n - 1, k - 1)

binomial(30, 1)
```

ERRORS:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    binomial(30, 1)
  File "main.py", line 13, in wrapper
    dictionary[cache_key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 31, in binomial
    return binomial(n - 1, k) + binomial(n - 1, k - 1)
  ...
  File "main.py", line 13, in wrapper
    dictionary[cache_key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 31, in binomial
    return binomial(n - 1, k) + binomial(n - 1, k - 1)
  File "main.py", line 13, in wrapper
    dictionary[cache_key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 31, in binomial
    return binomial(n - 1, k) + binomial(n - 1, k - 1)
  File "main.py", line 18, in wrapper
    old_cache = dictionary[cache_key]
KeyError: (10, 0)
```

As I understand, that is just recursive errors, but I can't understand why they appear.

I tried to run this decorator on fibonachi numbers function (fib(10)) with cache capacity of 3, but it return an error. WHY?

Comment: What did the error say? That usually answers the question "why?"

Comment: @Mark When I had run it in pycharm, it just made a pointer on the string "old_cache = dictionary[cache_key]" and wrote "KeyError", when I had run it in Jupyter, it just crahsed.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you edit the question to include the complete code that creates the error you are seeing (including your fibonacci function)?

Comment: @Mark I added errors

Comment: This is a tricky bug. Each call to the function can recursively call the function twice, which means your dictionary length increases by two before the function returns. This can result in a state where the dict length is 21 but the key is not in the dict. Try putting `print(len(dictionary))` right before `old_cache = dictionary[cache_key]`.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't fully understand your statement)

Comment: Admittedly hard to explain. I would print the length of the dicts and try to understand why the length is not increasing by one. How do you get to a state where the length is greater than `max_size`? When you do, you end up in the `else` statement despite the key not be set.

Comment: @Mark But why when I try to cache fibonachi function with cache capacity equal to 2, dictionary is always growing. How to fix it?